# Customize EPiserverDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have installed Episerver cms alloy site. I am new to episerver CMS. I need to customize the ‘EPiserverDB’ and registration page to accommodate new fields.Please find the list columns that is created on the ‘AspnetUsers’ table by default.

[image]

As per our requirement, I need to add new fields 'FirstName', 'LastName' and 'Age' on the registration page

How can I implement this?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Episerver. You should probably tag this question with ASP.NET Identity and EntityFramework. But it probably already exist questions about this topic. A quick search for how to extend an user in ASP.NET Identity should yield you a lot of guides and the official documentation.